# Executing two observables sequentially and wait for both to complete

Tags: rxjs

I want the done to print only after the first and second is printed.

```
const obs1 = new Observable<any>((observer) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first');
    observer.next();
    observer.complete();
  }, 10000);
});

const obs2 = new Observable<any>((observer) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('second');
    observer.next();
    observer.complete();
  }, 1000);
});

from([obs1, obs2]).pipe(concatAll()).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't complete any of the two source Observables so no operator can know what you consider as "done". This means you could use `merge` or `combineLatest` and only handle `next` notifications.

However, if you know they'll always emit just once you can `complete` each source and then use `forkJoin` or `concat`:

```
const obs1 = new Observable<any>((observer) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first');
    observer.next();
    observer.complete();
  }, 10000);
});

...

concat(obs1, obs2).subscribe({
  complete: () => {
    console.log('done');
  }
});
```

Comment: The order is not maintained here. second is displayed first.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Then use `concat` but you'll have to handle only the `complete` notification in your observer. Otherwise you can use `toArray()` to collect all emissions from both source Observables.